# How to change style in javascript using a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to prompt the user for a CSS property and a value and change the style of the paragraphs but I can't get the property working

```
function change()
  var prop = prompt("Enter a css property");
  var val = prompt("Enter a value for the property");
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.prop = val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the style `prop`, not the variable that's inside `prop`. Use brackets to signify prop is a variable, and to use the value contained inside of it:

```
x[i].style[prop] = val;
```

Here is a working demo:

```js
function change() {
  var prop = 'color';
  var val = 'blue';
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style[prop] = val;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Will turn blue</p>

<button onclick="change()">Turn paragraphs blue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```js
function change(){
  var prop = prompt("Enter a css property");
  var val = prompt("Enter a value for the property");
 var x = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style[prop] = val;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button onclick="change()">Change Style</button>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```